# Using a favicon in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, favicon

What's the best way of handling a favicon.ico in Zend  framework? I have seen alternatives that requires modification of phtml files like:

```
$this->headLink()->headLink(array('rel' => 'favicon',
                              'href' => '/img/favicon.ico'),
                              'PREPEND')
```

or modifications on .htaccess file.

Thanks,

Comment: Define "best way". There certainly are many different ways you can do it, but depending on how you want it to function (same for all pages?) and how your site is currently setup, the "best way" can vary a lot.

Comment: @Niklas: You are right there are many different methods. Actually that's why I am puzzled. I'm trying to use a single favicon.ico which is supposed to be the same for all the pages. I modify my layout/phtml files according to the first alternative I presented in the question but the icon does not change (it's still the default zend-framework icon). It's for sure that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: did you also `echo $this->headLink()`? Because just assigning it won't display anything unless you somewhere in your view/layout actually output the contents of `headLink`

Comment: @Niklas: Yes I also echoed it but still getting the old zend icon. I also copied favicon.ico to each folder in my root to test it `<?php
$this->headLink(array('rel' => 'favicon',
                                  'href' => 'favicon.ico'),
                                  'PREPEND');
echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Zend Framework Quickstart Application</title>
  <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/global.css') ?>
  <?php echo $this->headLink()?>
</head>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three choices:

- Do nothing - if the favicon is named favicon.ico and sitting in your public directory, most browsers will pick it up
- Hard-code the `<link>` tag into your layout
- Programmatically add the link tag as in your code example

Personally I would go for option 2. There's little point programmatically adding the favicon if it will always be there. It might make sense if the favicon was different for different users, e.g. say your application had a themes system with different favicons for different themes, then you might want to use headLink().

Browsers tend to cache favicons for a long time, so as long as the link tag is appearing in your HTML source then it will eventually update. You can speed up the process by changing the filename, viewing the favicon directly in your browser and/or clearing your browser cache.

Comment: using option2 i was able to show the favicon at mysite/public only. the other links still show the good old zend favicon. I don't really understand why and where that default icon comes from. Thanks for your time and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

you just move the favicon.ico file into the folder public! ;)

Comment: thanks but unfortunately does not work.. I still get the default zend favicon(a blue Z with lighter blue background). I already copied it to everywhere to test it. Neither Firefox nor chrome or IE was able to show the favicon. I tested it using a newly created zend project but it was not fruitful.

Comment: maybe a cache problem! have you tried to empty it and restart your PC?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if **rel** attribute being "favicon" expected things not working, until i've change above attribute to "shortcut icon" (tested under Firefox 5.0 Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

```
//in controller
$this->view->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'href' => '/themes/kieuhung/images/favico.png', 'type' => 'image/x-icon'), 'PREPEND');

//and in layout
echo $this->headLink();
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

The ZF2 skeleton application includes a default favicon.ico at `/public/img/favicon.ico`. Just change that file and you're good to go.

Can also help to force the browser cache to refresh the file by pointing it to that file path explicitly.